# How to toggle a boolean value with livewire and checkboxes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to create this filter thing with check boxes.

[image]

I am trying to toggle the state of the check boxes to be true or false

```
<x-input.checkbox wire:click="$toggle(free_trial)"/>
```

```
    public $free_trial = false;
    public $free_forever = false;
    public $pay_per_user = false;
    public $progressive = false;
```

When I do this approach, I am not sure how to make the inverse work, so if it is unchecked It would be false. Is there a way to add something to this, so if it's clicked again it would change it to false?

```
<x-input.checkbox wire:click="$set('free_trial','true')"/>
```

Any help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<x-input.checkbox wire:click="$set('free_trial',{{ $free_trial ? 'false' : 'true' }})"/>
```

I prefer dev this kind of login in a backend method.

```
<x-input.checkbox wire:click="toggleProperties('free_trial')"/>

public function toggleProperties($property)
{
   if($property == 'free_trial')
      $this->free_trial = !$this->free_trial;
   elseif(...) //.....
}
```